# Connect Google Cloud SQL to MySQL workbench

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have just create my Google Cloud SQL. I am using the ip address that I get i.e:160.200.100.12 the root as user name and the password that I have setup. I cannot connect with workbench and get the error: "failed to connect to MySQL at:160.200.100.12 with user root". Any idea what it may be wrong?

Comment: have you added your IP to the allowed list?

Comment: I get the IPv6 address that gave me in first page. Then i went to "access control" and add IPv6 address to Authorized Networks. It automatically create then an IP address.Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: have you added *your* IP to the Authorized Networks list?

Comment: you mean my laptop Ip?

Comment: yes. it only allows connections from authorized IPs.

Comment: Ok thanks I just did...

Comment: Do check e.g http://test-ipv6.com/ -- it IS possible that your laptop's IPv6 is not reaching your GCS due to internet provider's vagaries.  BTW you're showing 160.200.100.12 -- an **IPv4** address -- so I'm not sure what you mean by "the IPv6 address that gave me in first page".

Comment: So, adding IP to the authorized network list solves the issue or not?

Comment: yes it solved the problem

Comment: My ISP wasn't supporting ipv6 address so I had to request ipv4 address and it worked

Answer (score 1):

From reading through the comments, I can see that there are two points of confusion.

In order to connect to your Cloud SQL instance, you must first authorize access for connection requests coming from your IP address (meaning the one provided to you by your ISP). It is important to not confuse this IP address with the one provided by Google. I recommend reading through the documentation on [‘Connecting from External Applications’](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/external).

Furthermore, there seems to be some confusion regarding the IPv6 address which is included with your Cloud SQL instance. If your ISP does not support IPv6 connectivity, then you will not be able to use the IPv6 address provided to facilitate connections. In this case, you will have to request an IPv4 address for your Cloud SQL instance.

Finally, it is important to note that while your IPv6 address is free to use, assigning an IPv4 address will incur additional charges. I recommend reviewing the [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#instance-ip) information for Cloud SQL so you can get a better idea of how this is calculated.

I hope that this information is helpful.